# Split string into array (uneaven column lengths)

Tags: php

I have a data fine being read in using file() and iterate over each row. Need to be able to split the string into an array of "columns". Problem is the columns are not even widths (60 chars, 40 chars, etc). Seems like all the functions to do this expect that the columns are a fixed size.

This will be performed on a large data file quite regularly so optimal performance is desired.

Example of data.

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX                                                   XXX XXX                 X         XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                             XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX                                                   XXX XXX                 X         XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                             XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX                                                   XXX XXX                 X         XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                             XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
```

Comment: so there is no standard delimiter? column width? character? What is the point of this output then? Human interpretation? Also give us an example of this *data*

Comment: Example added. No standard delimiter. Yes standard column with for each row but with with of each column differs.

Comment: what do the `X`'s represent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward method would be using substr to split up the columns:

```
foreach (file($fn) as $i=>$line) {
    $rows[$i] = array(substr($line, 0, 60), substr($line, 60, 40), substr($line, 100, 30));
}
```

But contrary to common wisdom it would be faster to use PCRE and a regular expression to split up the string:

```
preg_match_all('/^(.{60})(.{40})(.{30})\K/m', file_get_contents($fn), $rows, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The disadvantage here is that it each row contains an empty `[0]` (would have contained the original line), and the data columns start at index `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could reliably do this is if there is some separator already in the file.

`explode()` splits strings on a separator, so if you know your file columns are tab separated, you can
`explode('\t',$string)`
to get an array of the columns.

Other than that, there's no reliable way I can think of that would let you pull out variable sized columns without previously knowing the size.

Comment: Can't use explode. I know the size of each column, it's always the same for each row, just differs between each column.

Answer (score 0):

After your comments on my previous answer, it appears that `substr()` is all you need.

If you know the width of each column for every line just do something like:

```
$rows = array();
foreach( $lines as $line )
{
  $columns = array();
  array_push($columns, substr($line, FirstColStart, FirstColEnd));
  array_push($columns, substr($line, SecondColStart, SecondColEnd));
  //more array pushing for each column
  array_push($rows, $columns);
}
//Do something with your 'row' array of columns ($rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with. I assumed that the column widths are not known ahead of time.

```
<?php

$data = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX                                                   XXX XXX                 X         XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                             XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX                                                   XXX XXX                 X         XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                             XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                  XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX                                                   XXX XXX                 X         XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                                             XXXXXXXXXXXXX           XX        XXXXXX';

$dataLines = explode("\n", $data);

// detect column breaks
$numDataLines = count($dataLines);
$colBreaks = array();
$c = 0;
while (true) {
    $rowEnds = 0; // count how many rows have terminated in the current col.
    $notSet = 0; // a special case of $rowEnds, when the line no longer has     
                 // chars.
    // run down each column. if there are no X's, then it is a col break.
    for ($r = 0; $r < $numDataLines; ++$r) {
        if (!isset($dataLines[$r][$c])) {
            ++$notSet;
            ++$rowEnds;
        } elseif ($dataLines[$r][$c] != 'X') {
            ++$rowEnds;
        }
    }
    // if no lines have chars left, end the while loop. this counts as a col 
    // break.
    if ($notSet == $numDataLines) {
        $colBreaks[] = $c;
        break;
    }
    // if no X's were in the line, this is a col break.
    if ($rowEnds == $numDataLines) {
        $colBreaks[] = $c;
    }
    ++$c; // move on to the next col
}

// now that we have all the col breaks, we simply iterate over them and slice
// out the needed sections from each line to create the columns.
$dataCols = array();
$left = 0;
foreach ($colBreaks as $cb) {
    // skip empty cols
    if ($left == $cb) {
        $left = $cb + 1;
        continue;
    }
    $colLen = $cb - $left;
    $dataCol = array();
    echo "left: $left, len: $colLen, cb: $cb\n";
    foreach ($dataLines as $dl) {
        $dataCol[] = substr($dl, $left, $colLen);
    }
    $dataCols[] = implode("\n", $dataCol);
    $left += $colLen + 1;
}

// tada!
print_r($dataCols);
```